# Vue JS How to bind the onChange event to change the value in input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, onchange

I am using npm package vue-range-component with which I change the value with a slider and then that value is reactively changed in the input

My problem is that I can’t apply the onChange event for inputs, I need to be able to change the value in the input, for example, put the number 70, and then this number was applied to the vue-range-component, something like that

Here is [my sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-fermi-sjxuu)

[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="app-content">
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="value[0]" />
        <input type="text" v-model="value[1]" />
    </div>

    <vue-range-slider
      v-model="value"
      :min="min"
      :max="max"
      :formatter="formatter"
      style="margin-top: 40px"
    ></vue-range-slider>

    <div class="multi-range-value-container">
        <p>{{ value[0] }}</p>
        <p>{{ value[1] }}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import "vue-range-component/dist/vue-range-slider.css";
import VueRangeSlider from "vue-range-component";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: [0, 100],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
    },
  },

  components: {
    VueRangeSlider,
  },
  created() {
    this.min = 0;
    this.max = 1000;
    this.formatter = (value) => `$${value}`;
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: There are limitations regarding array reactivity in Vue. Assign a new array instead of mutating its elements

Comment: please show me some example code

Answer (score 3):

One [caveat of Vue's reactivity system](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) is that you cannot detect changes to an array when you directly set the value of an item via its index.

As explained in the link, there are two main methods of making array modifications reactive:

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)

// Array.prototype.splice
vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

Using these methods forces the VueJS reactivity system to update its state.

To implement this solution in your example, you can use a watcher on a modelled value, an `@change` event or a `@keyup` event.

A watcher is likely the most resource intensive approach. I would suggest using `@keyup` (which would fire on every keypress as opposed to when you unfocus the input with `@change`) and then [debouncing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) the input if the value is used to filter/sort/load anything.

If you wanted to as well, you could also directly set the entire array.

For example instead of setting `value[0] = something` you could do `value = [...value, something];`and this would be reactive.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed Vue reactivity [issuse](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

You can fix it by not using `v-model` syntactic sugar but split it like this:

From:

`<input type="text" v-model="value[0]" />`

to:

`<input type="text" :value="value[0]" @input="changeRange(0, $event.target.value)" />`

define a method:

```js
methods: {
  changeRange(index, value) {
    const v = parseInt(value, 10) // value from input is always string
    this.$set(this.value, index, v)
  }
}
```

#### Update

Above code is a fix you would need anyway **but unfortunately** the `vue-range-component` has a different issue as it blocks all user keyboard input to **any** `input` element on the same page - see [this](https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/issues/21) and [this issue](https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/issues/18)

It was already fixed by this [pull request](https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/pull/5) but it wasn't released yet to npm

You can use some of the workarounds described in the issues BUT given the way how the maintainer (not) handles the issue, it would be probably better for you to look around for another component with similar functionality...

Comment: Levy I tried this option, but it did not work, you can be convinced of this by trying it out, apply your option in my sandbox code, the link is under my question

Comment: You are right. It is really strange. I am sure that it is a bug of the component you chose - it is capturing all keyboard inputs - https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider/issues/21

Comment: You are really right, if you had not said this, I probably never guessed the essence of the problem